Shopify: Error coming from `bundle install`
I am getting error.
I am trying the Shopify Remix app. The error occurs when I add the extension in my app and run Shopify app dev.
Any idea how to resolve this?
Here is error in the text

Shutting down dev because of an error ...
external error ─────
Error coming from bundle install
Command failed with exit code 5: bundle install
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory: C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/shopify-gems-nodejs/Cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/wdm-0.1.1/ext/wdm
C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r
./siteconf20240530-23416-8k4hiz.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lkernel32... yes
checking for windows.h... yes
checking for ruby.h... yes
checking for HAVE_RUBY_ENCODING_H... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
creating Makefile
current directory: C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/shopify-gems-nodejs/Cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/wdm-0.1.1/ext/wdm
make DESTDIR= clean
current directory: C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/shopify-gems-nodejs/Cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/wdm-0.1.1/ext/wdm
make DESTDIR=
generating wdm_ext-x64-mingw32.def
compiling entry.c
compiling memory.c
compiling monitor.c
compiling queue.c
compiling rb_change.c
compiling rb_monitor.c
rb_monitor.c: In function 'rb_monitor_run_bang':
rb_monitor.c:509:29: error: implicit declaration of function
'rb_thread_call_without_gvl' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
509 | waiting_succeeded = rb_thread_call_without_gvl(wait_for_changes,
monitor->process_event, stop_monitoring, monitor);
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:246: rb_monitor.o] Error 1
make failed, exit code 2
Gem files will remain installed in C:/Users/xxxxx/AppData/Local/shopify-gems-nodejs/Cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/wdm-0.1.1 for
inspection.
Results logged to C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/shopify-gems-nodejs/Cache/ruby/3.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/3.0.0/wdm-0.1.1/gem_make.out
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:93:in run' C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:44:in block in make'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:36:in each' C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:36:in make'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:63:in block in build' C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tempfile.rb:317:in open'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:26:in build' C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in build_extension'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:193:in block in build_extensions' C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:190:in each'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:190:in build_extensions' C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:837:in build_extensions'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:76:in
build_extensions' C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in install'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:206:in
install' C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in install'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
install_from_spec' C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:132:in do_install'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:123:in
block in worker_pool' C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in apply_func'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in
block in process_queue' C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in loop'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
process_queue' C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90:in block (2 levels) in create_threads'
An error occurred while installing wdm (0.1.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
In Gemfile:
wdm
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies...
Fetching ffi 1.15.4 (x64-mingw32)
Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
Fetching wdm 0.1.1
Fetching rb-fsevent 0.11.1
Installing wdm 0.1.1 with native extensions
Installing rb-fsevent 0.11.1
Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
Installing ffi 1.15.4 (x64-mingw32)
Fetching rb-inotify 0.10.1
Installing rb-inotify 0.10.1
Fetching listen 3.7.1
Fetching bugsnag 6.24.2
Installing listen 3.7.1
Installing bugsnag 6.24.2

Tried reinstalling various versions of Ruby but no luck.

Ruby+Devkit 3.3.1-1 (x64)
Ruby+Devkit 3.2.4-1 (x64)
rubyinstaller-devkit-3.0.6-1-x64 ( as suggested here )


solved
first uninstall ruby from windows program and features.
now delete all ruby folder and msys folder from c drive.
Install this ruby kit  Ruby+Devkit 3.1.2-1 (x64)
now after running command it will ask to update bundler so run : gem install bundler
then it worked.

Hi, this version worked for me (Ruby+Devkit 3.1.2-1 (x64))
also, I additionally searched the entire c:\ drive for any gems/ruby/wdm/ff

Any insight on why 3.1.2 in particular works and not any version before or after? The latest ruby dev kit for 3.1 is the 3.1.6 one and it didn't work for me. Was 3.1.2 the latest when you attempted this?

It worked for me as well actually. I came from https://github.com/Maher4Ever/wdm/issues/27. Probably that was the version exactly before RB_OBJ_TAINT became deprecated

I also had the same issue when I was trying to setup my shopify theme dev environment.
I solved it by installing ruby 3.0.7-1-x64 with devkit and it worked.
Here's the download link for ruby with devkit

I did tried this as well before posting but it did not work for me in app dev

this one worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78617137/23467046
also in this version (Ruby+Devkit 3.1.2-1 (x64), I additionally searched the entire c:\ drive for any gems/ruby/wdm/ff

gem install wdm -- --with-cflags=-Wno-implicit-function-declaration

above command worked for me as mentioned in
https://github.com/Maher4Ever/wdm/issues/27 originally referring to https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/840 -->
if above doesn't work, you can a also try updating budle config using below.
bundle config build.ffi -- --with-cflags=-Wno-implicit-function-declaration

and then try running
bundle install


Clang now reports an error when you use a function without an explicit declaration when building C or Objective-C code for macOS (-Werror=implicit-function-declaration flag is on). This additional error detection unifies Clang’s behavior for iOS/tvOS and macOS 64-bit targets for this diagnostic. (49917738)
Blockquote

